# Error while import imblearn.undersampling

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, python-3.7, imblearn

[image: Error]

I am getting "no module name sklearn.cluster" error while importing imblearn_undersampling module. I do not get error while importing SMOTE from imblearn as shown in the pic.
Some of the solutions i have tried: 
-Uninstalled and reinstalled sklearn, scikit learn, scipy using conda and pip3
- Uninstalled and reinstalled imblearn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not get this error with below version so please try with below combination and try to import again.

scikit-learn (0.20.2)
Python 2.7.14
imbalanced-learn (0.4.3)

Thanks,
Rajeswari Ponnuru.